# Series of $\int_0^z \zeta^{-1} \sin \zeta d \zeta$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a homeworkquestion so I would appreciate some good hints. I have $f(z) = \int_0^z \zeta^{-1} \sin \zeta d \zeta$. Can this be written as a power-series in $\mathbb C$ around $z = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What is the power series for $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ around $z=0$?

Answer (score 0):

You have for $z\in\mathbb{C}$,
$${\sin(z)\over z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^n z^{2n}\over (2n + 1)!}$$
from the Taylor series expansion. This is an entire function.

Comment: I may switch integral and sum here to derive a power-series for $f$ ?

Comment: The convergence of this power series is uniform on any compact subset of the plane.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Eventhough the hint of Thomas and uniform convergence of the series is enough to work it out :)

Answer (score 0):

$sin(\xi)$ can be expressed in the form of Taylor expansion as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\xi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\xi-\frac{\xi^3}{3!}+\frac{\xi^5}{5!}+...+$

$$\int_0^z \frac{sin\xi}{\xi}dz=\int_0^z\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\xi^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}dz=\sum\limits_0^{\infty}\int_0^z \frac{(-1)^n\xi^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}dz=\sum\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(2n+1)!}$$

The question is That I can't make sure the order of sum and integration can exchange.